How to disable caps lock in Windows 11?
I have a new Win 11 HP laptop and the suggestions from MakeUseOf for a Registry hack and for using NumLocker do not work:
Guessing it's the same Regedit trick but different keymap.
Note:  Either disabling it or mapping it to left Shift would be fine; I never want to TYPE ALL CAPS!

Registry
There is a new Registry edit, per How-To Geek. You can download the zip from them or save these as .reg files depending on which you want to use.
Change Caps Lock to Shift
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,2a,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00

Disable Caps Lock
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,00,00,3a,00,00,00,00,00

PowerToys
You can also use the Keyboard Manager utility in PowerToys to remap keys.


That does it - thank you for this very useful fix!  Now it's just  Left Shift.

Absolutely agree that cap locks is too easy to hit.
A fix that works on keyboards for all operating systems, whether Win 11, Mac, Linux or Android:

Pop off the key cap.
Put soft foam or a rubber O-ring as a shim on the post.
Replace key cap.

A thick, stiff, shim will completely block key press, a thinner, softer, shim allows a hard press to activate Caps Lock, but with tactile feedback.
Of course, you could try PowerToys to remap Caps Lock to another key or to nul -- which might, or might not, work, depending on the hardware keyboard encoder. However, that should also fix the On-Screen Keyboard.
